# Failed to execute 'put' on 'Cache': Request method 'POST' is unsupported - PWA Service Worker

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm creating a PWA with react. Although it passes lighthouse test and it's installable, I keep seeing these two errors in my console. The errors are logged numerous times as I browse through the app.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'put' on 'Cache': Request method 'POST' is unsupported
        at Cache.put (<anonymous>)
        at worker.js:20

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'put' on 'Cache': Request scheme 'chrome-extension' is unsupported
        at Cache.put (<anonymous>)
        at worker.js:20
```

> Line 20 is cache.put(event.request, resClone);

Here is the code in my worker.js file

```
const CACHE_NAME = 'My App';

// Install a service worker
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
    console.log('Opened cache');
});

// Cache and return request
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.respondWith(
        fetch(event.request).then(res => {
            const resClone = res.clone();
            caches
                .open(CACHE_NAME)
                .then(cache => {
                    cache.put(event.request, resClone);
                });
            return res;
        }).catch(err => caches.match(event.request).then(res => res))
    );
});

// Update a service worker
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
    const cacheWhitelist = [];
    cacheWhitelist.push(CACHE_NAME);

    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then((cacheNames) => Promise.all(
            cacheNames.map((cacheName) => {
                if (!cacheWhitelist.includes(cacheName)) {
                    return caches.delete(cacheName);
                }
            })
        ))
    );
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Your service intercepts same requests from chrome-extension. You have to ignore these requests.

```
if((event.request.url.indexOf('http') === 0)){ 
    //your request 
}
```